# Disable component selection in SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, components, mouselistener

What I'm trying to do is to draw with my mouse on four labels that are in a composite with box layout via a paintListner, added to each label. Furthermore each label has a MouseMoveListener which adds every mouse point to an ArrayList. Here's the code for one Label l:

```
l.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
    public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
        compLocation.setLocation(l.getLocation().x, l.getLocation().y);
        pointsToDraw1.get(n).add(new Point(e.x, e.y));
        l.redraw();
     }

});


l.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
     Device device = Display.getCurrent ();
     Color red = new Color (device, 255, 0, 0);
     e.gc.setBackground(red);
     for(Point p : pointsToDraw1.get(n)){
        e.gc.fillRectangle(p.x, p.y, 4, 4);
     }

    }

});
```

When I move over the Labels with my mouse everything works fine (see top part of the example image). As soon as I push the left mousebutton and keep it pushed while drawing, I only draw on the label I startet to push the button (see bottom part of the example image). This is because I automatically select the label by clicking on it. Is it possible to somehow disable this automatic selection and just check if the left mouse button is pressed? I only want to draw when the left mousebutton is pushed.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a Listener to `SWT.MouseDown` to each Label and setting `event.doit = false;`? That _could_ prevent the selection.

Comment: That doesen't really work. Still the same problem. I added the following:
    Listener listener = new Listener () {
 public void handleEvent(Event e) {
     e.doit = false;
 }
    };
    l.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);

Comment: What do you mean by "I automatically select the label by clicking on it". What do you mean when you say that the label gets _selected_?

Comment: @WaqasIlyas I guess he means that the Label he clicks on gains focus.

Comment: @user1643687 Did you try calling `setFocus()` and `forceFocus()` on the parent `Composite` of the labels from within the `SWT.MouseDown` Listener?

Comment: I don't understand why the label gaining focus would be a problem for the drawing of the line... labels don't gain focus unless they have key events anyway.

@user1643687 are you sure you are calling redraw on the other labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working sample. It should do what  you are looking for

```
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    final Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    shell.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {

      @Override
      public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {

         p.x = e.x;
         p.y = e.y;

         shell.redraw(p.x,p.y,2,2,true);

         for(Control c: shell.getChildren())
         {
           if(c.getBounds().contains(p))
           {
             Point t = e.display.map(shell, c, p);
             p.x = t.x;
             p.y = t.y;
             c.redraw(p.x,p.y,2,2,true);
           }
         }

      }
    });
    PaintListener painter = new PaintListener() {

      @Override
      public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

        e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        e.gc.fillRectangle(p.x, p.y, 2, 2);

      }
    };
    shell.addPaintListener(painter);
    final Label l = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    l.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 40);
    l.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
    l.setText("Label1");
    l.addPaintListener(painter);
    l.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {

      @Override
      public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {


        p.x = e.x;
        p.y = e.y;

        Point t = e.display.map(l, shell, p);

        Rectangle bounds = l.getBounds();
        if(bounds.contains(t))
        {
          l.redraw(p.x,p.y,2,2,true);
        }
        else
        {
          p.x = t.x;
          p.y = t.y;
          shell.redraw(p.x,p.y,2,2,true);
        }
      }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
```